# finger and who commands usage

Tags: linux, shell, command-line

I know that the `finger` command used to display information about local and remote users.

`finger` --> display users log in on local machine, even if remotely.

`finger @hostname` --> display users log in on the remote machine.

`finger user@hostname` --> I don't know what is it used for?

and `who` command used to know info about the local machine users only, is it true?

Comment: Is this question about `finger` or about `who`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### who

"Displays information about the users currently logged in to the local machine" - who man page. You can also specify a file for who to read from, like old logins file.

### finger

Displays information about the user (being local or remote if a host is supplied) or all users if no username is supplied. **finger** provides much more information about user login, when he logged-in, idle time, etc. .. It is much more informative than who.